# How to access the files inside the assets folder in an angular project using capacitorjs

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

Im trying to read a few .wav files from my assets folder in my Angular v15 project. I use Capacitor v4 to compile my app for iOS as well. Currently I have the following setup:

```js
this.mySampler = new Tone.Sampler({
      C4: 'assets/audio/myFile.wav',
    }, () => {
      // do something
    })
```

When I serve the app and view it in the browser, my files are correctly loaded. But I cant achieve the same results when I emulate the app on the iOS simulator.
I have tried using the [@capacitor/filesystem](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem#readdir) plugin to achieve this but i was not successful.

I used the following code to read the files within a directory as described in the documentation:

```js
const myFiles = await Filesystem.readdir({
      path: './src/assets/myAudioFolder',
    });
console.log('data:', myFiles);
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
main.js:23 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Folder does not exist.
Error: Folder does not exist.
```

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?

Comment: @O'Rooney After hours of searching I found my solution from [here](https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/issues/556#issuecomment-674407057)

Comment: @ilpianoforte If you can sum it up and post it as an answer to your own question, then I am sure it will help others